# How to set flag for user punch in & punch out in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

The first condition is working, the flag is set to 0 if it is 1
but it cannot turn back to 1 on click punch in button. this is the model function.called login_info_model it store the date & time of punchin & punch out.

```
function login_info_model($id)
{
    $reg = "%Y:%m:%d:%h:%i";

    $data = array(
        'logindt' => mdate($reg) ,
        'userid' => $id
    );

    $qry = $this->db->insert('registry', $data);

    if ($qry) {
        $on = array(
            'flag' => 1
        );
        $off = array(
            'flag' => 0
        );

        $flg = $this->db->get('users', 'flag');

        if ($flg == 1) {
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $this->db->where('flag', 1);
            $this->db->update('users', $off);
        } else {
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $this->db->where('flag', 0);
            $this->db->update('users', $on);
        }

        return $qry;
    }
}
```

Comment: or will this work $ert="IF(users.flag = 1 THEN SET flag = 0) ELSEIF (users.flag = 0 THEN SET flag = '1' END IF)";

    $this->db->update('users',$ert);

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your problem. Furthermore, the way you formatted the code is not helping readability.

Comment: its more readable now , this is a function in code igniter model class  it supposed to store the date & time , set tinyint- field called flag on table users..to 1/0 as user clicks on punch-in / punch-out  button in the view.

Comment: k0pernikus anything?

Comment: Are you sure that the update method is called when you try to re-enable it?

Comment: The first thing I would check is what is the exact value of `$flg`? If it's not what you expect, it will default to setting the database value to 0.

Comment: $flg gets the data from field named flag in table users. it has a default value of 0 . whenever user clicks punchin button the field is updated with $on which is 1 (its working). & else the field flag has a value of 1.its supposed to update it with $off which is 0..(not working, i use the same button to do both punch in & punch out , i dont know why i have to call the function twice as its executed whnever the button is clicked)

Comment: sorry about that guys, just rookie mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the problem.

```
$this->db->select('flag');

$this->db->from('users');

$this->db->where('id',$id);

$flaggg=$this->db->get();

$flagg=$flaggg->row_array();

$flg=implode("",$flagg);
```